# Find Transactions that do not have a particular type of related row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Transaction and Transaction_Status

Transaction has transaction_id and Transaction_Status has transaction_id and status_code

Transaction

```
Transaction_ID
1
2
3
```

Transaction_Status

```
transaction_id status_code
1              Created
1              Executed
1              Completed
2              Created
2              Executed
3              Created
```

Can anyone help me to write a query that can give me the transaction ids which are executed but not completed

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select transaction_id  
from Transaction_Status
where transaction_id  not in (select transaction_id 
from Transaction_Status
where status_code = 'Completed')
and status_code = 'Executed'
group by transaction_id
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8b5aec400c568afdcd7195680a0481b)

Comment: Hi @user2532244 was this answer of help to you?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
select transaction_id
from Transaction_Status ts
where status_code in ('Completed', 'Executed')
group by transaction_id
having min(status_code) = max(status_code) and -- only one status code
       min(status_code) = 'Executed';
```

Actually, you can use the alphabetic ordering of the codes and simplify the `having` to:
    having min(status_code) = 'Executed'

Answer (score 0):

select transaction_id
from Transaction_Status
where transaction_id  not in (select transaction_id 
from Transaction_Status
where status_code = 'Completed')
and status_code = 'Executed';